# C# picture box displays picture in wrong orientation

Tags: c#, orientation, picturebox

I have a winform application with a picturebox but when I load a picture it displays an portrait photo rotated on his side.
In the windows explorer the picture is displayed the right way.

Here is the only code I use for the picturebox:

```
Bitmap photo = new Bitmap(file.FullName);                
pbPhoto.Image = photo;
```

The picturebox SizeMode is set to "Zoom", other options are set to default.

PS. the pictures I use are from an iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rotation is being handled by data stores in the EXIF data of the image.  The image itself is being displayed correctly - Windows Explorer automatically rotates it for you, since the iPhone stores info in the image saying that it was taken "rotated".

You can examine the EXIF data and rotate the image yourself, but this is something you would need to do when reading the image.  The [EXIFextractor library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11305/EXIFextractor-library-to-extract-EXIF-information) on CodeProject will allow you to extract the information, which can then be used to [rotate the image to correct the orientation](http://automagical.rationalmind.net/2009/08/25/correct-photo-orientation-using-exif/).

Comment: Ah this is what is needed, but I can't add the EXIFextractor library to my references because it's an 4.0 application

Comment: I now used [ExifLibrary](https://code.google.com/p/exiflibrary/wiki/ExifLibrary) and that one is working